# X window Server Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, linux, x-server

On the web there are many manuals showing how to connect from Windows to Linux and get an X session window but do not indicate otherwise, that's my concern: How to view linux Windows programs with Protocol X [X window server]?

Sorry for my poor English ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. **VNC**

   - Install a VNC server on the Windows machine. You can use [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php) for example. Make sure you configured it to listen on a non-loopback IP address and it is not blocked by a Firewall.
   - Install a VNC client on the Linux machine. If you use Debian or Ubuntu, you can do it with the following command in a terminal:

     ```
     $ sudo apt-get install xtightvncviewer
     ```
   - Connect to the Windows box (assume the IP address of the Windows machine is is `192.168.1.10`):

     ```
     $ xtightvncviewer 192.168.1.10
     ```
2. **RDP**

   The standard Windows Remote Desktop Protocol. At usual it does not require any special configuration on the Windows side except setting `Allow users to connect remotely to this computer` checkbox in `System Properties` and adding a user to `Remote Desktop Users` group.

   On the Linux side you got to:

   - Install the `rdesktop` client. For Ubuntu or Debian you can use the following command:

     ```
     $ sudo apt-get install rdesktop
     ```
   - Connect to the Windows machine (assume its IP address is `192.168.1.10`):

     ```
     $ rdesktop 192.168.1.10
     ```
3. **X11**

   If you run an X11 server on a Windows machine (`Cygwin/X` or `Xming` for example) then the communication is pretty straightforward as the X window system was designed to be network-transparent. The main thing that we touch is an application can be *executed* and *displayed* on different machines. You run an application locally, but specify a **DISPLAY** where the application is shown.

   In your case the Windows box (say `192.168.1.10`) *runs* an application and the Linux box (say `192.168.1.11`) *displays* the application. In fact, the windows machine does not require to run an X server to *run* the application - it simply can *display* it on a remote Linux box:

   ```
   $ DISPLAY="192.168.1.11:0" xterm
   ```

   When you run the command on a Windows machine it will *run* `xterm` locally, but *display* it on a remote X server which runs on a separate machine. When you run the command on a Windows machine you should see the terminal window openned on a Linux machine (remotely).

   The `DISPLAY` is an environment variable that holds an address and number of the current display. Every X application looks into this variable to know where to render itself. The important thing to understand is the `xterm` (for example) does not distinguish whether it *displays* itself to a local X server or a remote X server. It is *network transparent*. For example, if you run `xterm` and just say:

   ```
   $ echo $DISPLAY
   ```

   It will print a *current* `DISPLAY` to which all applications *display* itself. By overriding this variable you tell the application to *display* itself somewhere else. I hope the concept is clear now.

   Note that it is likely your Linux X Server rejects all incoming connections for security reason. To allow connections from your Windows box run the following command:

   ```
   $ xhost +192.168.1.10
   ```

   Actually this way is a bit insecure, because everybody who assigns this IP address to itself may connect to the X server.

   Fortunately, there is a great and secure way. Since the X server just listen a TCP port - we can forward it to a local machine over an encrypted channel using `ssh` which has this awesome feature. You will need an ssh daemon running on the Windows machine. You can use `openssh` from `cygwin` - it is easy, just set up the `cygwin` with selecting the `openssh` package and then open a terminal and run `ssh-host-config`, but don't forget to set `X11Forwarding yes` in `sshd_config`.

   Now, how it looks like. On a Linux box you run:

   ```
       $ ssh -X user@192.168.1.10 xterm
   ```

   And after entering the password you should see the `xterm` window which is *executed* on a Windows machine but *displayed* on a Linux machine. After authorization `ssh` binds to a port on a Windows machine where it listens for connections and forwards packets over the established channel to a local port on a Linux machine (usually 6000 for display 0). Then it runs the `xterm` with setting `DISPLAY` to the bound port allowing `xterm` to *display* itself on a remote X server over an encrypted channel. In this case you don't need to run `xhost` since the X server does not need to accept any external connections.

   Now, how to *run* application on a Linux box and *display* it on a Windows box:

   On a Windows machine you will need an X server (`Xming` for example) and an SSH client (`PuTTY` for example). First, ensure the `Xming` running (there is a tray icon). Then, open `PuTTY`, choose `ssh`, fill `login` and `password` boxes, also ensure the `X11 Forwarding` in `SSH` settings is checked. Then just click `connect` and after that it will connect to the Linux box with opening a terminal window. You can run `xterm` there and it will be *displayed* on a local `Xming` server (since it is forwarded by `PuTTY` to a remote machine). Also look at [this](http://rcc.its.psu.edu/user_guides/remote_display/xming/) guide - there are some screenshots.

Comment: Hey vdmit11, please explain me a little more the last step (step 3), I use Xming X terminal but can not find it anywhere ......

Comment: I can not find the X terminal...

Comment: OK All is clear now, but.. in the moment: ssh -X user@192.168.1.10 xterm (changed the ip and the user for the my) return error = xterm: not found...

Comment: It is not found because it is not installed on your windows machine. You can't run a non-X application over the X protocol. You can't run explorer.exe for example, but you can install xterm or any other X application. I actually have no Windows machine right now so I can't install Xming to check what applications are there. You better to try in opposite direction: connect through ssh to a linux machine, run xterm there, but display it on the forwarded Xming.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much I will continue my search and you gave me a way.

Comment: As the answer points out, a popular option is to install `cygwin` with `X11` support.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not support the X protocol.  What I would do is look for something that talks Windows RDP (remote desktop protocol).  An example, not personally verified, might be [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/).

Comment: thanks but no single protocol that starts some unwanted programs and not all the Desktop

Comment: Unfortunately, RDP is what it is.

Comment: RDP *does* have a single-program-per-connection mode.

Comment: yes grawity, and this is my need